# How enable GPU accelerated video encoders in FFMPEG, Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, cuda, ffmpeg, encoding

How enable HW accelrated encoding in FFMPEG, Ubuntu 19.04 ?
(at least _nvenc variants of h.264/h.265 encoders)

**Do you know simplified user friendly way, how to do that using TASKSEL or similar automated tools ?** Thank you for any advice.

(my configuration: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 / nVidia binary drivers version 418.56, nvidia-cuda-toolkit installed)

---

```
$ ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc
```

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-0ubuntu1
Codec 'hevc_nvenc' is not recognized by FFmpeg.
```

---

btw, my cuda acceleration works perfectly in BLENDER CYCLES ... so it works in general, but not in FFMPEG

Answer (score 10):

I've found simple solution ...

just remove ffmpeg package

```
sudo apt remove ffmpeg
```

and install **SNAP package instead**

```
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

And thats it, you can use *_nvenc codecs now. They are already included in snap package. No need to download header files, no need to complile anything.

*Tip: If you have ubuntu version 19.04, be sure to give the ffmpeg package all permissions (especially access to external storage) in the software center.*

Comment: +1 because after a lot of years with this issue, this is the one I would recommend. One stop solution, future-proofed

Answer (score 0):

The version 4.2.4 Can recognize encoder=hevc_nvenc properly
(I have same gtx 1060 on Linux Ubuntu, so I have tested it on 20.04)